# Apache VirtualHost setting to force https

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, bitnami

Trying to force all traffic into https on AWS (ec2/Bitnami/Wordpress).

Current setting in httpd-vhosts.conf is...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress.example.com
    ServerAlias www.wordpress.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Can I simply replace the ServerAlias with a Redirect like...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.wordpress.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm thinking that the redirect would not only consolidate sessions into the canonical "www" but also make them HTTPS.

Will it work that way, or do I still need the ServerAlias directive?

And if needed, does the ServerAlias come before or after the redirect?

And finally, if the ServerAlias comes after the Redirect and does not include "https://...", does that allow non-HTTPS sessions?

BTW, I tried the [Bitnami suggested solution](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#how-to-force-https-redirection-for-an-application) below but it does not work...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to edit this file:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf
```

Adding...

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

According to Bitnami, [this edit](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#how-to-force-https-for-all-applications) forces all apps running on Bitnami to load in https. Since wordpress is the only app I have running, this solution worked for me. The Bitnami instructions for [forcing https just on wordpress](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#how-to-force-https-redirection-for-an-application) **did not work** for me.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Developer here. The instructions you used were meant for using the Bitnami LAMP Stack. We will update the documentation for Application Cloud Images like Bitnami Wordpress. In this case, you would have to edit the `httpd-app.conf` file, not the `httpd-prefix.conf` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule /<none> / [L,R]
```

Restart Apache:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

And now the redirection will be forced.

Comment: Well your docs say "How To Force HTTPS Redirection For An Application?
Add the following in the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf file inside the first VirtualHost directive:" so if that does not work for your WPress package you should note the exception.

Comment: We are improving the documentation to make this information clearer. Thanks! Was the issue solved?

Comment: Yes, I simply stayed with editing /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf to force https on all applications.

Comment: Any improvement so ar? I follow your instructions and still not pointing to https

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are on the correct path. I am using a permanent redirect and it works flawlessly.

RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://www.wordpress.example.com$1

Also, since your redirecting to https, the document root and other config aren't required. All your configuration will need to happen on your https virtual host.

Comment: I added your directive and restarted apache but I'm still getting non-secure sessions. I assume you're using only "ServerName wordpress.example.com" and your "RedirectMatch..." directive?

Comment: At the beginning of the virtual host for port 80, I am setting only the ServerName, ServerAlias and then the above redirect. Everything else has been commented out. Also, double check you don't have a DocumentRoot set in the general apache2.conf or any other conf file referenced.

Comment: In /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/http.conf I have (and left in place)...
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">

However, I was able to force https by following the Bitnami docs and editing /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf to force https on all applications, not just wordpress.